# Kubernetes cluster using Vagrant not working after restart

Tags: kubernetes

I installed a Kubernetes cluster by following the instruction here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/vagrant.md

Everything looks fine the first time. I'm able to see the nodes, pods, deploy new pods, etc.

The problem shows up when I stop the cluster and try to start it again. I'm restarting the cluster as indicated on the documentation:

```
vagrant halt
./cluster/kube-up.sh
```

When I do that I see the following error:

```
 Comment: Source file salt://kubelet/kubeconfig not found
 ...
 Minion did not return. [No response]
```

Then, when I check the status of nodes it says the minion is NotReady.

If I have VirtualBox open while I run kube-up.sh, I see that the error is thrown before the minion VM is started. So it sounds like the minion is not running when it tries to configure it. That's just an observation, not sure what's the problem.

In order to solve this issue I have to destroy the cluster and create it again, what downloads and install everything again, making it very slow to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this problem on GitHub:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/9270

Here it was suggested to use the code in HEAD. I did that and now it is working fine.

Comment: I was having this problem with v1.1.3, so I tried HEAD as suggested. Now, at the end, it hangs after a warning that the Salt provisioning process could loop forever if there's an error. Looks like that's what happens (after 3 attempts so far).